# Superview border is cutting into subview

Tags: ios, uikit

I'd like this subview to extend past its superview, but the superview's border is cutting into the subview.  Is there a way to prevent this?

[image: Example]

```
class TheView : UIView {

    let theSubView = UIButton()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        clipsToBounds = false

        addSubview(theSubView)

        theSubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        theSubView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 50, height: 50)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Oh, you mean so that the grey border is hidden by the green square?

Comment: Yeah that's right

Comment: Interestingly in the debug view hierarchy, the border is displayed under subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the view's layer's border, draw the border yourself:

```
class TheView : UIView {

    let theSubView = UIButton()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.gray.set()
        UIBezierPath(rect: rect).stroke()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = false
        isOpaque = false

        addSubview(theSubView)

        theSubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        theSubView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 50, height: 50)
    }   

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might also want to set `contentMode = .redraw`.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot make the view's own border appear under the contents of subviews. This is documented in (for example) the [CALayer `borderWidth` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410917-borderwidth):

> It is composited above the receiver’s contents and sublayers…

One way to fix it is to add a separate subview just to draw the border, and place the border-drawing view below the button. Example:

```
@IBDesignable
class TheView : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    private let borderView = UIView()
    private let button = UIButton()

    private func commonInit() {
        borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        borderView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        borderView.frame = bounds
        addSubview(borderView)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 50, height: 50)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot of result]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to redesign the structure of your views so that `theView` doesn't need to worry about what's outside its bounds.
For example, you can have both the bigger and smaller rect as subview. Then put the smaller rect over the bigger one. Then it should be able to cover the border line.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving this problem too. And even with rounded corners on border.
Here is a solution.

Add function to subclass of UIView:

```
- (void)addBorderWithRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corner
{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];
    CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
    borderLayer.lineWidth   = 1.0f;
    borderLayer.strokeColor = mainColor.CGColor;
    borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    self.layer.mask = borderLayer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

And call this function from awakeFromNib:

```
[self addBorderWithRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take another View as a reference, so that your two Views now have the same status (as subviews of another View), then you can overlay them including their frames. You can select which subview should be in front with:

```
myNewView.insertSubview(myWhiteViewWithBorder, at: 0)
myNewView.insertSubview(myGreenView, at: 1)
```